# Is kNN viable when predictors are normally distributed and the data is unbalanced?

Tags: machine-learning, k-nearest-neighbour, discriminant-analysis

I'm considering a 3-dimensional ($X_{1}, X_{2}, X_{3}$) classification problem where $X_{i}\sim N(0,1)$; observations are to be classified into one of 8 categories ($2^{3}$), reflecting (High, Low) combinations.

However, due to the normal distribution of the predictor variables, we expect to find less observations at more extreme values and vice versa, where more extreme observations can sometimes be closer to less extreme observations than its peers; also note that the classification acts to separate extreme observations, from non-extreme observations.

Is kNN still viable, or is linear discriminant analysis a better choice in this context?

Comment: How exactly the response variable (used for LDA) is defined?

Comment: Same as for kNN, 8 potential classes. whereas the predictor variables are normally distributed random variables